How to correctly evaluate the performance of a LoraModel after loading the trained model weights?
I'm trying to fine-tune the parameters efficiently, the idea basically consists of using a pre-trained base LLM model and adapting it to a specific task, that is, training the last layers of the model on a new, different data set. I managed to train the model and evaluate it successfully on my custom dataset, but the problem I'm facing is when evaluating the model again: after I load the model weights it returns very different results (worse) than what I got. previously before saving, it's as if it had never been trained on my dataset, follow my collaboration with the complete code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lwzWgnS-za4de2AvjPNV1O9sIczhPbyG?usp=sharing
See the code example:
from peft import PeftConfig, PeftModel

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

#after I finish fine-tuning parameters efficiently, I evaluate the model and have these results:

trainer.evaluate()

OUT:

{'eval_loss': 0.6273983120918274,
'eval_accuracy': 0.78,
'eval_runtime': 9.5016,
'eval_samples_per_second': 10,525,
'eval_steps_per_second': 2,631,
'epoch': 15.0}

#Save the model settings:

config=lora_model.config

#Save model and tokenizer weights:

lora_model.save_pretrained("gpt-lora")

tokenizer.save_pretrained("lora-tokenizer")

#I load the weights again:

model_name="gpt-lora"

lora_model2 = GPT2ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name, config=config)

okenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("lora-tokenizer")

lora_model2.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

lora_model2.config.pad_token_id = lora_model2.config.eos_token_id

trainer = Trainer(
model=lora_model2,
args=TrainingArguments(
output_dir="./data/sentiment_analysis",
learning_rate=2e-3,
\# Reduce the batch size if you don't have enough memory
per_device_train_batch_size=4,
per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
#label_names = \["start_positions", "end_positions"\],
num_train_epochs=10,
weight_decay=0.01,
evaluation_strategy="epoch",
save_strategy="epoch",
label_names=\["labels"\], 
load_best_model_at_end=True,
),
train_dataset=tokenized_data\["train"\],
eval_dataset=tokenized_data\["validation"\],
tokenizer=tokenizer,
data_collator=DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer=tokenizer, padding="max_length"),
compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

#The Problem happens here, when evaluating the model after fine-tuning:

trainer.evaluate()

OUT:

{'eval_loss': 3.2905619144439697,
'eval_accuracy': 0.17,
'eval_runtime': 9.3529,
'eval_samples_per_second': 10,692,
'eval_steps_per_second': 2,673}\`

Please help me, I've tried everything and I couldn't!
thank you guys!
#I tried to load the model like this after training, but it didn't work
from peft import AutoPeftModelForCausalLM

lora_model2 = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("gpt-lora")

